# Cloud Communications API recordResponse initial and max silence

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

Using the cloud communications API and remote media to play a prompt and record the response in a Teams channel bot. When setting parameters for the recording we're able to set the initial and max silence timeouts but these seem to have no effect on the recording length. The recording will always finish when the max duration is reached.

```cs
var request = this.RequestBuilder.Communications.Calls[callId].RecordResponse(
                prompts: prompts,
                bargeInAllowed: false,
                initialSilenceTimeoutInSeconds: 5,
                maxSilenceTimeoutInSeconds: 2,
                maxRecordDurationInSeconds: 120,
                playBeep: false,
                clientContext: callId).Request();
```

Is there something missing, unfinished functionality or a permission required?

Comment: If you're using Recordresponse() calll, then it helps you to record a short audio response from the caller. A bot can utilize this to capture a voice response from a caller after they are prompted for a response. Please note that this action is not intended to record the entire call. The maximum length of recording is 2 minutes. I think thats why you're seeing the same that you dont see any effect on recording length.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't phrase my question properly. I can record up to the maximum duration (2 min) and this works as expected. However, I'm expecting the initial or max silence parameters to "cut short" the recording and return a notification before the max recording duration is reached.